# Hydra infestation

Tags: aquarium, fish, parasites, shrimp

Recently I’ve noticed a hydra infestation. I’ve pulled out about 5 hydras already, but I know there are some left. One of my golden back shrimp have already lost their life to the hydra’s paralysing, poison but how do you get rid of them?

I have 10 gallon tank with a filter and many driftwood and plants and rocks and a bunch of micro fish and shrimp and baby shrimp.

[image: my baby shrimp sharing food]

I am so far putting salt treatment since they are affected with another parasite (shrimps).

Please tell me a shrimp baby safe way without taking out the hydras or any fish or shrimp.

Okay, and I don’t want to use chemicals! Only normal household items. I don’t want to see 20 baby shrimplets dead in the morning!

Comment: This may be useful https://www.thesprucepets.com/combat-aquarium-pest-hydra-1381228

Comment: Thanks but it doesn’t say really say anything that helps me greatly...

Comment: What is a normal household item that isn't a chemical, tweezers?

You generally have 2 options, find something that eats hydra, or remove everything from the tank and treat it chemically, but do not use anything copper if shrimp will "ever" be in the tank though.